# Why does the "collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status" keep coming?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I'm a beginner in Coding. I'm trying to write a code in C. Uptill this code every code was running smoothly. But after writing the following code the Visual Studio Code is giving errors. The most repeated was `collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`. I saved the code before running. I tried reinstalling the `gcc MinGW compiler` and Visual Studio Code IDE but nothing happened. I also tried the `Geany IDE` but it is showing the same error. What should I do?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    int mian(){
         int marks[4];
         marks[0]=34;
         printf("Marks of Student 4 is %d",marks[0]);
         return 0;
    }

PS D:\Codes> cd "d:\Codes\CPrograms\" ; if ($?) { gcc arrays.c -o arrays } ; if ($?) { .\arrays }
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Does fixing the spelling of your `main` function fix it?

Comment: Please read error messages from top to bottom. Don't start at the last line. That is only a summyary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Error: Id returned 1 exit status (undefined reference to 'main')
```

This error is occurred on following cases,

1. If `main()` is not written in lowercase, like you used `Main()`, `MAIN()`, `mAin()` or anything else.
2. If `main()` does not exist in the program or by mistake you `mistyped` the main().

In your case you mistyped the main()
change `mian()`--> `main()`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
     int marks[4];
     marks[0]=34;
     printf("Marks of Student 4 is %d",marks[0]);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had 3 files:  musicplaylist.c  musicplib.c  musicplib.h

CMakeLists.txt looked like this:

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)`

`project(adv)`

`add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} musicplaylist.c musicplib.h)`

The mistake was .h file in place of .c file.

Changing to `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} musicplaylist.c musicplib.c)` helped solve the error